# Can I get WebGL in chrome to render with the AMD rather than Intel graphics card?

Tags: catalina, google-chrome, webgl

When I go to https://kepler.gl/demo/ukcommute it's enormously slow on my Macbook Pro which has a Radeon Pro built in.

It looks like WebGL is being rendered using the Intel graphics card. Is there a way to force it to use the AMD one? I have hardware acceleration enabled in chrome, and other things use the AMD card just fine.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to find something to do that programatically and ended up here.